# Inline Styles with <a>

Tags: html

I am trying to make my link url font bigger in size and in bold, **Without changing the css**. I am trying to use inline styles.

I expected this line to work:

```
<p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;><a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>scp/"><?php echo __('sign in here'); ?></a></p>
```

However I get black text with no hyperlink.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the attached CSS on this node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing closing quote `"` after `font-size:24px;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;"><a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>scp/"><?php echo __('sign in here'); ?>Sign in here</a></p>
```

- You need to close the quotes`"`.
- You need to have a text inside `<a>some text here</a>` the tag.